# GDPR: youtube-nocookie embedded URL's, need visitors' permission?

Tags: javascript, cookies, iframe, youtube

This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow and I have a question about the GDPR.

Hi there! (This is ment to be on top of the post, but for some reason it gets deleted when I save it)

**Situation:**

On my website I don't want to bother visitors with cookie notifications, so the goal is to only place necessary cookies. However, there will be embedded YouTube video's on the website, which usually places tracking cookies.

After some research I stumpled upon the youtube-nocookie.com domain, which I am using now. Without using that domain, an embedded video url will be:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/7cjVj1ZyzyE
```

With using it, it is:

```
https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/7cjVj1ZyzyE
```

By using the latter, cookies will only be placed after playing the video, and no tracking cookies will be placed (according to Google: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en under 'Turn on privacy-enhanced mode'). However, there will still be placed some cookies, and it is not clear for me if visitors will need to give permission for those, and if so, under what category (and maybe they are still tracking?).

Image of the cookies:

[Image of cookies youtube-nocookies.com places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yoUV.png)

This is in Chrome. The cookies from the gstatic domain are placed on page-load for some reason. That doesn't happen in Opera.

Another weird thing is that FireFox (with allowing all cookies and trackers) and Edge don't seem to place any of the 6 cookies from the image at all.

Many sites and blogs say that this is **the** way to embed YouTube video's, but I can't seem to find a clear answer to the question if you still need visitors' permission for these cookies. Also on many sites where I only accept necessary cookies, I still have the possibility to view YouTube video's and the corresponding cookies will be happily placed without my consent.

Has anybody delt with this before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some more research I think I found a clear answer. From a report of Cookiebot:

> “Privacy-Enhanced Mode” currently
> stores an identifier named “yt-remote-device-id”
> in the web browser’s “Local Storage”. This
> allows tracking to continue regardless of
> whether users click, watch, or in any other way
> interact with a video – contrary to Google’s
> claims. Rather than disabling tracking, “privacyenhanced mode” seems to cover it up.

Source: https://www.cookiebot.com/media/1136/cookiebot-report-2019-ad-tech-surveillance-2.pdf

The 'yt-remote-device-id' indentifier, along with some other ones, are, even with the use of the youtube-nocookie.com domain (or 'Privacy Enhanced Mode'), still being placed on page load (given that the iframe with the set source is already part of the DOM at this point of course).

So while no tracking 'cookies' cookies are placed, the tracking has moved to the browsers localStorage (I overlooked this before), which basically means visitors actually do need to give permission before embedded YouTube video's with Privacy Enhanced Mode enabled should be loaded on the page.

**Update**

Gave some nuance in response to Marc Hjorth's comment.

Comment: This is not entirely true. The localStorage is being set when the YouTube API is called, which you can control. The localStorage is also removed when the API is no longer needed. E.g. I make a call to embed a youtube video in a modal and change the host to the nocookie domain, and the localStorage is deleted when closing the modal. If it's allowed by GDPR, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

i can confirm that the localStorage entry effectively replaces the funktion of the cookie. it is persistent and makes you identifiable across browser sessions. i get the same "yt-remote-device-id" value each time after restarts. only erasing the local storage makes a difference.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).